# Warning: include(ArrayAccess.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, error, varien-autoload

How can i solve this error:

> **Warning:** include(ArrayAccess.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [...]**/lib/Varien/Autoload.php** on line **94**
>
> ...
>
> **Fatal Error:** Interface 'ArrayAccess' not found in [...]**/lib/Varien/Object.php** on line **36**

[image]

Comment: A good question has a **specific title** and contains code or error messages as **text**, not screenshot. Please take more care when writing questions. It should not be necessary to have a chat or 20+ comments every time. Also please stop asking the same question twice, you already got banned once for that.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/ArrayAccess) interface is part of PHP core since 5.0, using it should **never** trigger the autoloader. Your PHP itself seems to be broken, try to reinstall it or contact your hoster.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jivan It may be possible That your lib folder has some problem try to reupload your lib folder from your local and try again.
And also check file permission that Lib folder has right permission or not

Comment: does 777 permission ok,,

Comment: No 755 to folder and 644 to files

Comment: Commands for  Permission             ` 1) chmod -R 644 ./*
2) find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
3) find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
4) chmod 550 ./mage`

Comment: i did what you told, but now i get 500 internal server error

Comment: You have fired this command ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/bP0MxhB.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44030/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-murtuza).

Comment: but i manually change the permission what you suggested

Comment: bro, again i get same error

Comment: make sure still we connected

Comment: Try to give permission from SSH access

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: Create SSH Access from your Cpanel If you Don't have SSH access and then try to connect with your terminal and with Putty if you are using windows

Comment: @ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44030/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-murtuza

Comment: shall i replace my lib from local host

Comment: Yes give permission on local and upload those file via FTP

Comment: may i know, why i get this error

Comment: NO One know Without sourcecode Or you if you are developer

Comment: i get same error after replace lib folder from local host

Comment: is any other solutions..